# Capture 3rd party app notifications in a pebble watchapp

Tags: ios, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, pebble-js

Is there a way to write a watchapp (for pebble time) which will capture notification from 3rd party apps coming from iOS?

For example, I want to capture WhatsApp notification and display it in my watchapp instead of the default notification UI.

Answer (score 0):

To get any notes from whatsapp, you're going to have to set up a notification listener like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                     selector:@selector(handleReachabilityChange:)        
                                       name:@"reachabilityChanged" 
                                       object:nil];
```

However, all the documentation on whatsapp.com shows that while there are APIs for *sending/sharing* something via whatsapp, there is no published API for *receiving* notification.

So there are two possiblilites:

1) Use some kind of system wide notification capture tool and see **IF** any notifications are being sent, then, if they are, use those, knowing they could stop at any update of whatsapp.

2) There is no way to get that directly from whatsapp.

Comment: Currently I am getting all the notifications from WhatsApp to the default notification center. I want to override it and send them to my app instead.

Comment: Your comment here is pretty much a repeat of your original question. We know what you want to do. Did adding an observer work? Have you used some kind of notification inspection tool (not just looking in the notification center) to inspect the posting of notification to reverse engineer the constants?